# What is the meaning of the sequence e with k superscript and n subscript vertically aligned? How does it look like given its definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, notation

I am stuck on an exercise in my linear algebra textbook--I will not provide the source as it is an Italian textbook used at my university. A solution to the problem is provided, but I am not able to understand it as I do not understand what a sequence like the one given should look like in the first place, and also what the writing means.

Here's the problem.

Consider the set $\{e^k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ where for each $k\in\Bbb N$ the sequence  $e^k$ is such that $$e_n^k=\{\begin{cases} 1\; \text{if}\; n=k\\ 0\; \text{if}\; n\neq k\end{cases}\quad \forall n\in\Bbb N$$

Required: show that $\{e^k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is linearly independent and that it is a basis of the vector space $W$, where
$W=\{x\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}: x \;\text{is eventually}\; 0\}$

The thing is that the $k$ and the $n$ in the sequence are, in my textbook, *vertically aligned* (I  just don't know how to write that here). The problem is then that I do not understand what a writing like that should mean, and what a sequence defined in this way could look like. Only then can I think about understanding and solving this (easy) exercise.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Do you mean they are written like this? $e^{kn}$. From the definition $e^k$ should be interpreted as the vector with a 1 in position $k$ and a 0 in all other positions. And the positions are indexed by natural numbers. You can think about it as a sequence which is always 0 except at the position $k$, where it takes value 1.

Comment: No, it is not written like that. k and n are vertically aligned, with k still being a superscript and n still being a subscript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We begin with the set $X$ of all sequences $${\bf x}:\quad{\mathbb N}\to{\mathbb R},\qquad n\mapsto x_n\ .$$
It is common to express such a sequence datawise as ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)$. This set $X$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space under coordinatewise operations.  In your problem we then take the subspace $W\subset X$, consisting of the sequences having only finitely many $x_n\ne0$.

Now we consider the special sequences $${\bf e}^k=(e^k_1,e^k_2,\ldots)\qquad(k\in{\mathbb N})$$
defined by
$${\bf e}^k:=(0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,0,\ldots)\ ,$$
where the $1$ is at place $k$ of the sequence. Putting the index $k$ in the upper position is just a typographical manoeuvre; no exponentiation is meant.

It is claimed that the infinite system $$\bigl({\bf e}^k\bigr)_{k\in{\mathbb N}}$$ is a *basis* of the subspace $W$. This means that for each vector ${\bf x}\in W$ you can find a finite $N$ and uniquely determined numbers $\xi_k\in{\mathbb R}$ such that
$${\bf x}=\sum_{k=1}^N\xi_k\,{\bf e}^k\ .$$